# how to remove or hide "full screen not available" message on a YouTube embedded video

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have an embedded youtube video that has been working successfully for years, however recently a message is displayed by default "Full Screen is not Available" with a link to "Learn More".  This message covers a portion of the video.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this message appearing.  This is a recent development.

Here is a fiddle that shows to problem https://jsfiddle.net/Lg1x7662/

```
<div>
```

This is an iframe with the video

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you tell us what browser you are using? (I can't reproduce the problem you are having with Chrome)

Comment: Sorry, this seems to have been some sort of transient problem that YouTube had. It now behaves correctly, the message only appears if you click the full screen button when full screen is not allowed for some reason.